# Active Directory TLS authentication issue (Windows Server 2019 & 2012 R2)

Tags: active-directory, ssl, certificate-authority, ssl-certificate-errors

I am facing an issue with **AD TLS** communication-related issues.

Six months before I could authenticate the user on SSL communication using the **CA certificate alone**.

Currently, I cannot authenticate with a CA certificate alone **instead I was able to log in using the following certificates.**

**CA certificate (LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE)**

**Client certificate (LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CERTFILE)**

**Client key file (LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_KEYFILE)**

I was wondering if any of you provide me with steps to disable  **LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT** option on the AD server-side or **any updates** on the **windows side** and fix for the same.

I am searching on the Internet and found an option to set the certificate option but it doesn't work for me.

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain the use case a bit more, against which workload ad ssl authentication is being used. And are you sure the certificate is not expired?i see a screenshot of iis, do you want to disable the cert validation there?

Comment: Hi @Turdie, I am trying to establish ssl communication with CA certificate alone. Some 6 months before it worked fine. Now it is not working with CA certificate alone instead while uploading three certificates(CA certificate, Client certificate, and Client key file ) from the client it is working now. I need to wonder why it is so? Is there a way or option to change the certificate validation.

Comment: `authenticate the user on SSL communication using the CA certificate alone.` describe the steps that the user will perform in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Client Certificates to ignore

Here is how to do that using PowerShell

```
# Import the WebAdministration module
Import-Module WebAdministration
# Specify the IIS site name (replace 'Default Web Site' with your site name)
$siteName = 'Default Web Site'
$site = Get-WebSite -Name $siteName
$site | Get-WebConfiguration -Filter "/system.webServer/security/authentication/clientCertificateMappingAuthentication" | Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Name Enabled -Value False

# Commit the changes
IISReset
```